# Java Bot SDK throws 401 error for proactive message

Tags: java, botframework

I'm trying to implement a bot to send proactive messages. I made a proof of concept in NodeJS that works:

```
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

adapter.onTurnError = async (error) => {
    console.error(error);
};

const cr = require('./test_cr.json');

adapter.continueConversation(cr, async (turnContext) => {
  await turnContext.sendActivity('Node SDK proactive message')
});
```

Yet when I try to recreate this example using the Java SDK, I get `com.microsoft.bot.connector.rest.ErrorResponseException: Status code 401, {"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`.

```
String appId = System.getenv("MicrosoftAppId");
String appPassword = System.getenv("MicrosoftAppPassword");

BotFrameworkAdapter bot = new BotFrameworkAdapter(new SimpleCredentialProvider(appId, appPassword));
ConversationReference cr = mapper.readValue(new File("test_cr.json"), ConversationReference.class);
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = bot.continueConversation(appId, cr, turnContext -> turnContext.sendActivity("Java SDK proactive message").thenApply(resourceResponse -> null));
cf.get();
```

The conversation reference and app credentials should be the same for both examples. Am I not setting up the Java bot correctly? For reference, I'm using a pretty barebones conversation reference:

```
{
  "channelId":"msteams",
  "serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
  "conversation":{
    "isGroup":true,
    "conversationType":"channel",
    "tenantId":"xxxxxx",
    "id":"xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your mapper is correctly creating the `ConversationReference` instance, and that all its fields are set correctly?

Comment: When I serialize the object back to JSON using `mapper.writeValueAsString()`, it looks the same. And when I access the fields of the Java object, they come back as expected. Perhaps there's some other required field that's missing, but the error message is not very descriptive.

Comment: @JosephBlair - Have you checked that your Java app is loading the appId and appPassword variables correctly? Have you tried sending a proactive message to a channel other than Teams? Have you tried the [Java echo bot](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/tree/main/samples/02.echo-bot) to send normal messages instead of proactive messages? Can you link to any documentation you've followed? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it could be an issue with BotTrustServiceUrl. I can't explain it but in one of my bots, I had to add this additional code to get proactive messages to work (specifically after a restart). Not sure if this is your same issue but it helped me.

```js
const { MicrosoftAppCredentials } = require('botframework-connector');

// Then in your proactive message section...

        const conversationReference = req.body.conversationReference;
        await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
            // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
            // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl

            MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(conversationReference.serviceUrl);
            await turnContext.sendActivity(req.body.message);
        });
```

Now I've also got two other bots where I didn't need to do this. The one that isn't working wihtout this code is using an older SDK so that could be it, both otherwise the proactive message functions are identical so I'm not sure.

EDIT: I misread the question and didn't notice that you were having trouble with Java SDK, not JavaScript SDK. But perhaps you could use the same method to see if this resolves your issue in Java as well.

Comment: I'm not sure why this wasn't required in the Node SDK, but you're right. Adding `AppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(cr.getServiceUrl());` fixed the problem.